# How to add gallery button to Camera open with intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

In my app users are able to make a photo with camera. And I start it using intents:

```
Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Now when open camera lacks the gallery button which would allow user to pick one of existing images from his SD card. Is it possible to show this button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really change the things camera intent has to offer, and if you do find a device where the camera app would let you access the gallery I wouldn't depend on it.

I would recommend that whenever your user taps on the button or whatever launches the Camera Intent, launch a dialog that asks you the user to choose, "New Photo" or "Existing Photo". If they choose existing, launch the gallery intent.

Here is a really good tutorial for the gallery intent.

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/gallery-intent-tutorial

Good Luck!

Comment: I am pretty sure you are wrong. I have seen apps where this was implemented. Facebook has it the other way round: a gallery with camera button.

Comment: @BartBurg, FB devs have created their own camera activity which gives them full reign to do whatever they please. The differences are outlined here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

The op wants to use an intent

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have a button that links to the gallery while the user is in the Camera view, then you probably will need to create a custom camera activity.  Android docs has a good explanation of how to get started: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html